# Placing some lighting pngs on the top right corner and bottom left corner of a div

Tags: html, css

I have a landing page I designed in Figma but quickly met challenges when implementing it. I have 2 transparent images that I want to place at the corners of my first div.
Here's a pic to understand more clearly

[image]

Now here's what I tried but it looks very hacky and I want a better way if possible

```css
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/zld1w9Q.png');
  background-position: 1300px -1000px;
  background-size: 100% auto;

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

what's the best way to do this while being responsive ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS only for that:

```
background: radial-gradient(circle at 90% 0,red 0, rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%), 
radial-gradient(circle at 10% 100%,blue 0, rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify Your code to match this style:

Parent div(container):

```
style="position: relative;"
```

Top-right image:

```
style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;"
```

bottom left image:

```
style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;"
```

Ensure that the images are still contained in the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

After googling around for hours and thanks to the answer by @digitalniweb. the best way to do it with is Radial gradient, I've used some website called mesh gradient generator and it allows me to freely move points around. I also added a little bit of blur and it looks exactly how I want it,

here's the code for my design

```css
background-color:hsla(0,0%,8%,1);
background-image:
radial-gradient(at 0% 100%, hsla(45,86%,62%,1) 0px, transparent 30%),
radial-gradient(at 100% 0%, rgba(181, 181, 181, 0.377) 0px, transparent 50%);
```